# How to achieve a multiple merged photograph

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

Can any one tell me how i can achieve multiplicity photography.

Please refer the link below.

**Let say a child is playing in garden and we are merging 10 to 12 images into a single image?**

[Google images examples](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=multiplicity%20photography&safe=off&espv=210&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=jhmwUpHoCsXwrQell4CgDA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1152&bih=749)

Comment: Do the linked answers not answer your question? If so, please indicate what is missing from those answers and make your question more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample are photoshop like creation.

Background with certainly 1 of the model occurence is the base and extracted model from other picture are then added with eventually a light/temperatur color correction to suite the base.

Extraction is standard extraction or automated by comparaison to different picture that select the difference